# Skin adhesive that can be used daily without damaging skin

Tags: medicinal-chemistry

What is the branch of chemistry that deals with skin adhesives? Is there an adhesive that is not water soluble that is safe to use every day?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the branch of chemistry that deals with skin adhesives?

Likely a combination of biomedical engineering and organic chemistry, with some materials science in there as well.

> Is there an adhesive that is not water soluble that is safe to use every day?

Yes. [Mastisol](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D634M8E) fits your criteria.